# Problem with autorization using api token Zendesk

Tags: php, api

I have next problem. I want to try integrate Zendesk in my application. Then I use Postman - no problem. I have error(401 unautorization ) in my app. I think this problem contains with headers. Can anybody help me? I am using GuzzleHttp .Below my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c49cB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loJhg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your code you need to specify what are you granting here is an JavaScript sample:

```js
  await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(user+":"+pass),
    },
    body: "grant_type=client_credentials"
  });
```

this should work.